# cast from [String:AnyObject] to unrelated type NSMutableDictionary always fails Warning

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, casting, nsmutabledictionary

Code is working, but how do I silent this warning that keeps on appearing every time?

```
let parentView = self.parentViewController as! SBProfileViewController
parentView.savedDetailsModel = SBSavedUserModel(data:responseObject["data"].dictionaryObject! as! NSMutableDictionary)
```

> cast from '[String:AnyObject]' to unrelated type 'NSMutableDictionary' always fails Warning

SavedUserModel stores saved information:--

```
class SBSavedUserModel : NSObject { 
var userId : String!
var firstName : String!
var lastName : String!
var imageBase64 : String!

required init ( data : NSMutableDictionary) {
    self.userId =  data.objectForKey("userId") as! String
    self.firstName = data.objectForKey("fName") as! String
    self.lastName = data.objectForKey("lName") as! String
    self.imageBase64 = data.objectForKey("image") as! String
}
```

Comment: Why do you want your dictionary to be mutable?

Comment: Because contents of the dictionary may change at runtime. As User can change/edit details any number of times. @Tommy

Comment: The code you've given us looks up four items from the dictionary and then never uses it again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try replacing

`responseObject["data"].dictionaryObject! as! NSMutableDictionary`

with this:

`NSMutableDictionary(dictionary: responseObject["data"].dictionaryObject!)`

You could easily cast it into a NSDictionary, but for some reason when you want a NSMutableDictionary, you have to initialize a new one with `NSMutableDictionary(dictionary:)`

*Edit*: see the comment on this question by @Tommy for why this is necessary.

Comment: The "for some reason" is that you're starting with an immutable dictionary. It's not odd that the language won't allow you to try to mutate it. "This object is immutable" does not mean "this object requires slightly more arcane syntax to mutate".

Answer (score 2):

Unlike `NSArray` and `NSDictionary` the mutable `Foundation` collection types `NSMutableArray` and `NSMutableDictionary` are not bridged to the Swift counterparts.

The easiest solution is to keep using Swift native types

```
let parentView = self.parentViewController as! SBProfileViewController
parentView.savedDetailsModel = SBSavedUserModel(data:responseObject["data"].dictionaryObject!)

...

class SBSavedUserModel : NSObject { 
var userId, firstName, lastName, imageBase64 : String

  required init ( data : [String:AnyObject]) {
    self.userId = data["userId"] as! String
    self.firstName = data["fName"] as! String
    self.lastName = data["lName"] as! String
    self.imageBase64 = data["image"] as! String
  }
}
```

---

Or – still more convenient if **all** values in the dictionary are strings

```
parentView.savedDetailsModel = SBSavedUserModel(data:responseObject["data"].dictionaryObject as! [String:String])

...

required init ( data : [String:String]) {
    self.userId = data["userId"]!
    self.firstName = data["fName"]!
    self.lastName = data["lName"]!
    self.imageBase64 = data["image"]!
}
```

Comment: Solution is correct however for some reasons I'm using NSMutableDictionary for mutable objects. Swift native types are always best choice if we are programming in swift only.

Answer (score -1):

Hope this way can help you:

`mutableDictionary as NSDictionary as? [String: AnyObject]`

same way works on NSMutableArray.